# Meteor: IF statement returning true but page showing false (showing user Facebook picture)

Tags: meteor

I am trying to show a facebook picture when the facebook user is logged in and a placeholder when a non facebook user is logged in.

I have created an if statement in my user_page html:

```
        {{#if facebookuserloggedin}}
        TRUE
        <img src="http://graph.facebook.com/{{facebookuser}}/picture/picture?type=large" alt="{{user}}">
        {{else}}
        False
        <img src="user.png" alt="stanley">
        {{/if}}
        <h1>Welcome {{user}}</h1>
```

and a helper that checks the facebook logged in status

```
 facebookuserloggedin: function(){
    FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
        console.log (response)
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            (alert ("true"))
            return true
        }
        else {
            (alert("false"))
            return false
        }
    });
```

For some reason the alert is showing that the helper is returning true (when facebook user is logged in)  but the html page shows false. Because of this the placeholder is displaying instead of the facebook profile picture.I really have no clue how this is happening could anyone help me out? Thanks in advance.

Comment: From what you have shown here it looks like your helper will always return `undefined`. The inner callback is called asynchronously, right?

Comment: What do you mean inner callback asynchronous? I am quite a beginner so do not fully understand the concept. The alert says true and the page says false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @apendua said, helper functions are synchronous, while you call an asynchronous function. In short, this means that the `return` statement you wrote is not a return statement for you **helper** function, but instead for the function you passed to `FB.getLoginStatus`. Notice that you used the `function` keyword twice, so you've got two functions there, and the return statement is in the wrong one.

This is a common trap for beginners, so don't worry, there's an easy fix. It requires storing your state in another place (like a local variable) and watching on it reactively.

There are few patterns you can use here. For the beginning, I recommend calling your asynchronous function in `rendered` callback and creating a separate dependency for the result. This should give you the best understanding on what is happening.

```
var status = null
var statusDep = new Deps.dependency();

Template.templateName.rendered = function() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        ...
        if(...) {
            status = true;
            statusDep.changed();
        } else {
            status = false;
            statusDep.changed();
        }
    });
};

Template.templateName.helpers({
    facebookuserloggedin: function() {
        statusDep.depend();
        return status;
    };
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! This has made a lot clear. Could you, if you have time, quickly explain what statusDep.depend() does?

Comment: In short: it will cause the function to recalculate whenever you call `statusDep.changed()` anywhere in the code. For more thorough explanation, read here: [http://docs.meteor.com/#deps_dependency](http://docs.meteor.com/#deps_dependency).